# Sum to infinity

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, geometric-progressions

*An infinite G.P.* has a finite sum with *initial term $u_1 = 2$*. Find *the sum to infinity* of this G.P. If it is also a **Fibonacci sequence**

My approach-

- since it is a G.P., $ u_3 = u_2 * u_2/u_1$
- since it is a Fibonacci sequence, $u_3 = u_1+u_2$
- Therefore, $u_2 * u_2/u_1  = u_1+ u_2$

By substituting $u_1 = 2$ and solving, I got $u_2= 1 \pm \sqrt{5}$.

When $u_2 = 1+\sqrt{5}$ ,

- $r = u_2/u_1 = (1+\sqrt{5})/2  \approx 1.618$
- $| r | = | 1.618 |$ = 1.618 > 1
- therefore the sum to infinity doesn't exist.

when $u_2 = 1-\sqrt{5}$ ,

- $r = u_2/u_1 = (1-\sqrt{5})/2 \approx -0.618$
- $| r | = | -0.618 | = 0.618 < 1$
  therefore the sum to infinity exists.

therefore, a= 2, r = (1-√5)/2

the sum to infinity $\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i = a / ( 1-r) = -1+\sqrt{5}$.

Can anyone pls help me if this is true? 
Sorry for my poor typing form.

Comment: please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thank you, I will try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning looks correct. I get the same answer you do in a slightly different form:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i &= \frac{a}{1-r}\\
& = \frac{2}{1-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}\\
&= \frac{4}{2-(1-\sqrt{5})}\\
&= \frac{4}{1+\sqrt{5}}
\end{align*}$$

(Since $1-\sqrt{5} < 0$, every other term is negative and the overall sum is less than the first term, $a=2$. )

Note that this is answer is equal to $-1+\sqrt{5}$, because:
$$\frac{4}{1+\sqrt{5}} = \frac{4(1-\sqrt{5})}{(1+\sqrt{5})(1-\sqrt{5})} = \frac{4(1-\sqrt{5})}{1-5} = \frac{4}{-4}(1-\sqrt{5})=-1+\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: I think r = (1-√5)/2 and only this is different. @user326210

Comment: @SteveLin Oh, you're right. I had a sign error!

Comment: You get a different answer? To me it looks like$$-1+\sqrt5=\frac{4(-1+\sqrt5)}{(\sqrt5)^2-1}=\frac{4(-1+\sqrt5}{(-1+\sqrt5)(1+\sqrt5)}=\frac4{1+\sqrt5}$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt After I fixed my sign error, I got the same answer you do. It looks correct now.

Comment: Then perhaps you could include these few steps and change the "although I get a different answer" to "I get the same answer differently"?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It is done.

Comment: @SteveLin Happy to help! :)